# Is there any real time example to write unit test cases for azure nodejs function using mocha or jest tool

Tags: node.js, azure, unit-testing, serverless

Is there any real time example  to write unit test cases for azure nodejs function using mocha or jest tool

Answer (score 3):

Testing an Azure Function is no different than testing any Javascript module exporting an async function.

One tricky part is passing a mocked context to the function under test. For this, you can use [stub-azure-function-context](https://github.com/willmorgan/stub-azure-function-context).

For a complete quickstart, you may want to check my blog post [Unit testing Azure Functions with Jest and TypeScript](https://www.maxivanov.io/unit-testing-azure-function-with-jest-typescript/)

Answer (score 0):

It's a good habit to extract the main functionality from a function in an own class/module/function. Because AWS Lambda, Azure Functions and GCP Function have a small changes in the interface and this will make migration much easier.

For example:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    // You can call and await an async method here
    return {
        body: "Hello, world!"
    };
}
```

Would be:

```
// keep just a single line of code here
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    return doAction();
}

const doAction = () => {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    // You can call and await an async method here
    return {
        body: "Hello, world!"
    };
}
```

And now you can a Jest test on doAction(), with plain Node, without coupling with Lambda/Functions code

Comment: I am a bit confused by this. How will you access the doAction function in your test file if you're not exporting it?